# BeautifulSoup returns empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping with python. I am using the BeautifulSoup to extract quotes from a website and here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = urlopen("http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/inspirational/")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

links = bsObj.find_all("div", {"class:" "quote"})
print(links)
```

It returns:

```
[]
```

But when I try this:

```
for link in links :
    print(link)
```

It returns nothing.

(Note: this happened to me for every website )

**Edit:** the propose of the code above is just to return a Tag but not the text (the quote)

Comment: Check with `_class`

Comment: try with this `bsObj.select(".quote")`

Comment: `bsObj.find_all("div", class_="quote")`

Comment: Thank you @Ananth I think your solution ust worked fine for me

Comment: The correct syntax is `links = bsObj.find_all("div", {class_:"quote"})`